# Making circles responsive to screen width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have created some html that is responsive but im having difficultly making the circles respond to the screen size.

I want the circles to shrink when the screen reduces in size.

here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MDne7/) to show my working

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12 image-container">
            <div class="left">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/cover2.jpg" alt="Cover 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg arrow-left">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg arrow-right">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/cover1.jpg" alt="Cover 1"></a>
             </div>
            <div class="right">
                     <a href="#"><img src="img/cover3.jpg" alt="Cover 1"></a>
             </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="information-wrap">
                    <h1>Issue Number:</h1>
                    <h2>Information about Magazine</h2>
                    <h3>More information..</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="more-info-wrap">
                      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large magazine-open">Open</a>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could set the `width` and `height` of the circles by percentage.

Also, to keep the circles at the middle, you could use a negative percentages for the `left` and `right` properties, as follows:

```css
.arrow-right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: -10%;   /* <-- keep the circle center horizontally */
    width: 20%;    /* <-- Set the width by percentage  */
    height: 20%;   /* <-- Set the height by percentage */
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 28px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.arrow-left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: -10%;    /* <-- keep the circle center horizontally */
    width: 20%;    /* <-- Set the width by percentage  */
    height: 20%;   /* <-- Set the height by percentage */
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 28px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/MDne7/3/)**.

Comment: You can shorten your code by removing vendor prefixes. They are not needed.

Comment: @dfsq But there's almost no harm in keeping them there no? Just in case? Or have all browsers adopted the W3C Way?

Comment: I removed the vendor prefixes in the posted code snippet, but they are still available in the Fiddle demo.

Comment: @MackieeE I just prefer clean code. The only reason to keep them if you want to support old devices. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

Answer (score -1):

change `height` and `width` to `percentages`

```
.arrow-right,.arrow-left{
height:34%;
width:34%;
}
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/MDne7/4/)